# Mouse movement increases code execution speed VB with C DLL

Tags: c++, dll, vb6

I have an old VB6 program that does numerical integrations with help of a C DLL, also compiled in VS6. (Yes, I know I should update the code to .NET etc, but it just works.)  Recently, I tried some more complex calculations than usual and noticed that the program runs faster when the mouse is moving in the main form.  That is, when given a particular large problem to integrate, the execution/integration takes about 5 seconds if the mouse is left motionless after clicking the command button, but it finishes in about 1 second if the mouse is moved around without clicking on the form.  Since the program also does optimizations of parameters to fit data, this makes a huge difference in the total time to do a fit.

I did some work to narrow down the source of the effect.  Mouse movement does increase the CPU clock frequency from 1600 MHz to 2600 Mhz, but this does not seem to be enough to give such a large increase on a single thread. In debugging, I found the integration routine executes the preliminary VB code up to the DLL call with no delay, and most of the calculation time is spent in the DLL function after passing the variables. Debugging in the DLL shows that most of the extra time is spent in the repetitive loops of the numerical routine, but there is no obvious reason the mouse movement would speed these up.

Is this just an effect of speeding up the CPU clock frequency, despite the huge reduction in execution time?  Or is there an alternative explanation?

Comment: `(Yes, I know I should update the code to .NET etc, but it just works.)`: The old adage of: 'If it's not broke then don't fix it!'

Comment: In `Power Options` in `Control Panel` try using `High Performance` plan instead of the default `Balanced`. (A particularly nasty feature on Windows server editions too.)

Comment: Locked the CPU at 100% using the high performance setting. No effect on the execution time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the problem.  It turned out to have nothing to do with the VB code or the processing speed, but instead it was entirely an issue in the C++ code of the DLL.  An If statement in the DLL looks for system messages in case the DLL execution takes a long time, specifically to allow for the user to cancel execution (via a button on a form).  In that sequence, GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) was used to check for cancel messages.  GetMessage will wait until a system message is received before allowing the execution to continue. Therefore, moving the mouse around on the main form is an easy way to send messages continually, and that would allow the DLL to run at more or less full speed.  With no mouse move, it would hang for a few seconds waiting for some automatically generated system message to fire. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx

The solution is to use PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) instead to check for a posted cancel message.  PeekMessage will look for a message and, finding none, will allow the execution of the main code to continue immediately. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.8almost5).aspx

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: PS - I was able to track down the GetMessage problem pretty easily using the debug features in VS2013, specifically the Performance and Diagnostics profiling of the DLL using Instrumentation (not Sampling) mode.  Rebuilt the DLL project in VS2013 first.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that it might be windows biasing the VB app process when it might receive input?  Sounds very random!

Try task manager -> processes -> right-click on your application -> Set Priority -> High

See if that produces similar results.

If it does, you can set the priority of a program in a few ways, one of them is starting using a batch file with the START command

```
START   ["title"] [/Dpath] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED] [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME] [/WAIT] [/B] [command / program] [parameters]
```